# IBM Worklight- pushnotifications

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

I am doing push notification configurations in IBM worklight(7.0) for the first time. I have downloaded a sample project for hybrid applications from the [IBM site](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.0/notifications/push-notifications-hybrid-applications/event-source-based-notifications/).

I am stuck with the below error... Kindly help me on this

```
000001ad com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.gcm.GCMMediator        W FPWSE1079W: GCM push token 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxxxxxXXXXXXXXXXXX' is not added to GCM notification key. GCM Service invocation failed (reason: Error while invoking request)
com.ibm.pushworks.server.exceptions.GCMException: GCM Service invocation failed (reason: Error while invoking request)
    at com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.gcm.GCMSender.sendToGCM(GCMSender.java:381)
    at com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.gcm.GCMSender.addTokenToAndroidKey(GCMSender.java:353)
    at com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.gcm.GCMMediator.addTokenToAndroidKey(GCMMediator.java:206)
    at com.ibm.pushworks.server.core.PushServiceImpl.getNotificationKey(PushServiceImpl.java:1848)
    at com.ibm.pushworks.server.core.PushServiceImpl.updateDevice(PushServiceImpl.java:658)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.updateDeviceToken(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:465)
    at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.handler.NotificationSubscriptionHandler.doPost(NotificationSubscriptionHandler.java:126)
    at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.GadgetAPIServlet.doGetOrPost(GadgetAPIServlet.java:176)
    at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.GadgetAPIServlet.doPost(GadgetAPIServlet.java:133)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
    at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.GadgetAPIServlet.service(GadgetAPIServlet.java:116)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1275)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:766)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:472)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:135)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:89)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter$1.execute(AuthenticationFilter.java:239)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:76)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:246)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:192)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:86)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:975)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1097)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:81)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:912)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:262)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:938)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1156)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:626)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:780)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: android.googleapis.com: android.googleapis.com
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1348)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1257)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1182)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:44)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:102)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:319)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:363)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:219)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:195)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:86)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
    at com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.gcm.GCMSender.sendToGCM(GCMSender.java:377)
    ... 30 more
```

Comment: when are you getting this error? please give reproduction steps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the main issue here is the following from the log:

> java.net.UnknownHostException: android.googleapis.com: android.googleapis.com

From Google's documentation:

> If your organization has a firewall that restricts the traffic to or from the Internet, you need to configure it to allow connectivity with GCM. The ports to open are: 5228, 5229, and 5230. GCM typically only uses 5228, but it sometimes uses 5229 and 5230. GCM doesn't provide specific IPs, so you should allow your server to accept incoming connections from all IP addresses contained in the IP blocks listed in Google's ASN of 15169.

Make sure all of these are in place and try again. This could very well be a network issue.